# htaccess is redirecting my wordpress wp-content folder too by mistake

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

ok, so i'm relatively new to .htaccess and redirects but I've been searching high and low for this solution and it's driving me crazy.

Right now I'm redirecting my old blogger blog to wordpress.

So, I have this code in place:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /2014/01(.*) /journal/trip1/$1
```

This redirects:

```
www.website.com/2014/01/BlogTitle
```

to:

```
www.website.com/journal/trip1/BlogTitle
```

This all works great EXCEPT it's also redirecting my images in the "*wp-content/uploads/2014/01*" folder because it matches the "2014/01" in the redirect

The image should be here:

```
http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/SomeImage.jpg
```

Instead it redirects to here:

```
http://www.website.com/journal/trip1/SomeImage.jpg
```

Like I said, I've searched high and low for solutions and I'm sure it's something ridiculously easy.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Todd

Comment: What happens if you put a `^` before `/2014`?  If memory serves it's a regular expression, so you should be able to force it to match only the start of the string that way.  Secondly, your browser will probably have cached the 301 (permanent redirect), so you might need to test on a second browser.  As a rule of thumb, use a 302 (temporary redirect) until you're sure you have your rule correct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Hobo, you are not checking from the beginning of the URI. This means that anything before `/2014/01` will also be matched. As such, you'll need to add `^` before the `/2014`. It should now look like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/2014/01/(.*)$ /journal/trip1/$1
```

As a rule of thumb, it's also better to end the expression with `$`.

Alternatively, you can use `mod_rewrite` to do the redirect. Using the condition and rule below, you can do the redirect whilst ensuring the requested URI does not map to an existing file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Make sure the request does not map to an existing file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# If so, redirect:
RewriteRule ^2014/01/(.*)$ /journal/trip1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Also, per @Hobo's comment, you should always do a temporary redirect instead of a permanent one when testing. Once you're happy with either of the above (i.e. they're working as expected) change both `302`s to `301`s.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  I knew it was something easy

Ironically, I have been using 302 for testing but changed it to 301 when I posted here to prevent people from saying "you know, 302 is only a temporary redirect" lol

Answer (score 0):

What if you apply the solution said by @MikeRockett and @Hobo, but, instead denying any found file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

deny only the images on your URI

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$
```

Not sure if it's the real solution. I'd say that in a comment, but I've got not enough points yet